# GWT-Platform + SmartGWT: Chained pop-up windows

Tags: smartgwt, gwt-platform

I got a login window which, depending on the RPC response, will show me another Window. What I'm wondering is how to initialize the second Window. I tried onReset and onReveal methods but is like they are never triggered, In addition, when resetting values, using destroy() will kill my Window permanently. I ended up with the following solution, but I feel is not too efficient, can someone recommend me a way to do it?

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
      if(result.getResponse().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                getView().getUsernameField().setValue("");
                getView().getPasswordField().setValue("");
                getView().getWindow().hide();
                memberWindow.setUsername(username);
                memberWindow.loadAppointments(new Date());
                ((Window) memberWindow.getWidget()).show();
    }else{
        SC.say("Error", "Login failed because: " + result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out something like this

```
@Override
  public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
    CurrentUser currentUser = new CurrentUser(getView().getUserName());

    LoginAuthenticatedEvent.fire(eventBus, currentUser);

    // notice the place manager call. The transitions between the pages are
    // done in GWTP through PlaceManager.revealPlace(PlaceRequest) call.
    PlaceRequest placeRequest = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.mainPage);
    getPlaceManager().revealPlace(placeRequest);

  }
```

Check out 
src\au\com\uptick\serendipity\client\presenter\SignInPagePresenter.java 
from the Serendipity application a sample of login done with SmartGWT + GWTP :

http://code.google.com/p/crmdipity/downloads/detail?name=Serendipity-0.6.0.zip&can=2&q=